# Query two sails.js instances with one query

Tags: node.js, sails.js, google-cloud-sql

I cannot work out if it is possible and how to query two sails models on my two different databases, different cloudSQL instances, with a single query, Model.find(). Basically too populate from two different models having two different connections.

I setup two different connections in connections.js:

```
MysqlServer: {
   adapter: 'sails-mysql',
   database: '..'
   ...
 },

MysqlServerStat: {
    adapter: 'sails-mysql',
    database: '..'
    ...
  },
```

Models: with relationship, but using two different connections

```
(d-stat)
module.exports = {
connection: 'MysqlServerStat',
attributes: {
   pro_id:{
     connection: 'MysqlServer',
     model:'pro'
   }..

(pro)
module.exports = {
   -default connection-
   attributes: {
     pro_d:{
        connection: 'MysqlServerStat',
        collection:'d_stat',
        via: 'pro_id'
    }..
```

ProController where I try and query from both connections at the same time:

```
Pro.find()
     .populate('d_stat')
```